# What is binary upgradability?

Tags: c++, effective-c++

I'm reading Scott Meyers's Effective C++.

In Item 30:Understand the ins and outs of inline.He refers to the concept of
binary upgradability.

Comment: Which edition? My copy of 2nd Edition has something different for item 30.

Comment: 3rd Edition @RogerLipscombe

Comment: IMO, it might be somewhat related to, does the change in the source file requires other classes that use it to be compiled again.

Comment: Could you please explain IMO?@UtkarshBhardwaj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By binary upgradability, Meyers (in *Effective C++, Third Edition*) refers to the concept of clients of a particular library only needing to re-link with newer versions of the library, instead of recompiling. If the library contains inline functions, binary upgradability may not be possible, causing clients to have to recompile.

Comment: In case of shared "dynamic" libraries (e.g. DLLs), even relinking may not be needed. Exchanging die dynamic library and restarting the process suffices.

Comment: Why does Meyers call it binary upgradability?What does this name come from?@TriskalJM

Comment: I assume he came up with it himself, as I haven't seen it elsewhere. As for why? The library binary can be upgraded without recompiling the client.